# How to avoid rendering the original object when using the geometry node?

Tags: geometry-nodes

I made this object using geometry nodes.

[image]

[image]

I want red objects not to be rendered.

What node should I use?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remove the Join Geometry node by clicking it and pressing Ctrl + X. Only the Realize Instances should be connected to the geometry output.

Comment: Although in the node setup above Ctrl+X would only keep the red object - but of course the instances should be connected to the output.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to see the red objects in the viewport to see what you're doing while editing but don't want to see them in the final render, you could use a *Switch* node in combination with the *Is Viewport* node.

Plug the *Is Viewport* into the *Switch* input, the instanced blue objects into the *False* input and the result of the *Join Geometry* node into the *True* input.

This way when *Is Viewport* is true i.e. watching the object in the viewport, you see both the red and blue objects. When you render the scene, the *Is Viewport* result is false and you only get the blue objects rendered.

[image: viewport switch]

If you don't need to see the red one in the viewport, simply don't join the geometry and plug only the instances in the *Group Output*.